# Getting back data returned by Lambda function and update my React App Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am having problem getting data returned by Lambda back to my React webapp
what should be done for this ?

[image]

```
const axios = require('axios');

// eslint-disable-next-line
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  console.log('Received S3 event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  // Get the object from the event and show its content type
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name; //eslint-disable-line
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key; //eslint-disable-line
  const awsRegion = event.Records[0].awsRegion;
  const imgUrl = `https://${bucket}.s3.${awsRegion}.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
  const customUrl = `https://demo-image-search-api${imgUrl}`;
  const response = await axios.get(customUrl);
  /******** I want this response back to react app to be rendered **************/
};
```

Comment: You're going to need a CORS implementation, either in your lambda or using API gateway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: If the AWS Lambda function is being triggered by Amazon S3 when the object is created, then **there is no return path available** to your app because the function was triggered by S3 rather than your app. Your app would either need to poll to check for the object, or perhaps read a message from a queue.

Comment: which approach is best all I want is image url from s3 and send api request and get data